# INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE but change single field

Tags: hive

I am looking to update a field for all items in a table if the value of the field is an empty string.

For context, I can get a count of the number of items that I need to update with this query:

```
select count(*) from ddb_table where someField = "";
```

I then want to update the items in this table where `someField` is an empty string. For example, I want to update `someField` to `"foo"` where the field is blank.

I imagine the `INSERT OVERWRITE` query would look something like this:

```
insert overwrite ddb_table select field1, field2, field3, field4, someField = "foo" FROM ddb_table where someField = "";
```

In other words, I'm wanting to "keep" all the original values for each item in the table, except for `someField`, which I want to update to `"foo"`. This update would only occur on items where `someField` is blank.

How do I do this?

Comment: Your `insert overwrite` looks correct. What is the issue you are facing with it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my original query:

```
insert overwrite table ddb_table select field1, field2, field3, field4, someField = "foo" FROM ddb_table where someField = "";
```

The result was that `someField` appeared to take the value that was in `field4`, and `field4` would get set to `FALSE`.

I then tried:

```
insert overwrite table ddb_table select field1, field2, field3, field4, "foo" as someField FROM ddb_table where someField = "";
```

This was slightly better, except that `field4` would be set to `"foo"`, and `someField` would be set to the value that was previously in `field4`.

Then I tried:

```
insert overwrite table ddb_table select field1, field2, field3, "foo" as someField, field4 FROM ddb_table where someField = "";
```

This one worked for me. For some reason moving the field that I want to change from the end of the list of fields to somewhere in the middle of the list of fields seemed to make it work.